# Visual Studio Publish Not Copying All DLLs to Publish Folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-2015, publish

I have a Web Project A which is my startup project and I publish from this web project.

A refers to another project -> B (A has project reference to B)

B contains a reference "**ref.dll**"

When I **build** B, all DLLs of B including "**ref.dll**" gets copied to bin folder of A

However, when I **publish** A, I cannot see the "**ref.dll**" in the published folder.

I learnt somewhere that Visual Studio is intelligent enough to not copy a DLL if the any of it's methods are not being used anywhere. In my case, I have verified that methods in "**ref.dll**" are being used.

Why is it so? Do I need to explicitly add reference to "**ref.dll**" in WebProject A, for it to appear in the publish folder?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting Copy Local = true for the dll which is in project B.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting bin folder, cleaning the solution and rebuilding again.?
If that dll is not in the bin folder ,what's error your are getting ?

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting bin folder, cleaning and rebuilding. Also, tried the same in a new workspace. Without that DLL, there is some business logic which fails, and on the browser it throws me the error page saying that DLL is missing. When I manually copy-paste the missing DLL, everything works fine.

Comment: What surprises me is that, when I build, that DLL is successfully copied to the bin folder and when I run the application locally even, everything is fine. It is only when I publish that the DLL is missing.

Comment: am also facing same problem dll is missing after publish any solution for this @AniruddhaPondhe

Comment: If you use nuget to manage packages, try to remove the item ref in csproj file.

Comment: I have this same issue.    project a references a dll  b which references a dll c.    a and b get published by c does not.